# Expanding Menu Bar Using only CSS

Tags: html, wordpress, css

in my blog http://www.anandu.info/ i use a nav menu(left) which expands on clicking and closes on clicking again,but that uses jquery is there a way to replicate it using only css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to use the :target pseudo, then you could make the button go to #menu, ID the part that is hidden as id="menu", and then style from there.

Comment: i have seen one with only css recently(that too in stack overflow).with  a different design.it is possible

Comment: Can you provide a link to what you're saying does that same thing as yours using only CSS?

Comment: i don't remember the link, but look at this code how can i use it. http://jsfiddle.net/5MUnd/

Comment: I've modified my answer. I had forgotten about the :target pseudo.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can do it with CSS only.